# Конструкция "Case of"

Tags: 1с, операторы

Добрый день, товарищи Хэшкодчане.

Сижу, значит, пишу конвертер в 1С, но в силу того, что саму 1С-ку знаю еще не очень хорошо, возник вопрос: есть ли в языке оператор типа "case of", как в делфи, например? Лучше бы его использовать, чтобы не клепать огромную кучу "Если - Тогда - Иначе...".

Согласитесь, что такая конструкция:

```
%Case_of%:

1: Тогда ...
2: Тогда ...
...
n: Тогда ...
```

выглядит лучше, чем огромное количество вложений "Если".

PS. *погуглил* в яндексе, но он мне ничего хорошего не сказал.

Comment: нагуглил, мб поможет http://help1c.com/faq/view/725.html

Comment: Хм... интересно, попробуем. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такой конструкции в 1С нету.

1. Используйте

   ```
   Если Тогда 
   ИначеЕсли Тогда
   ... 
   КонецЕсли;
   ```
2. Создайте структуру, список значений, массив... это для случая подстановок.

ЗЫ Использовать Запрос для switch - лишний раз дергать сервер, т.к. запросы доступны только в толстом клиенте, внешнем соединении или на сервере.